# Как реализовать выбор валюты на сайте?

Tags: php

Рассматриваются только модули для Joomla, OpenCart, Prestashop и так далее. Про то как реализовать выбор валюты на самописном сайте на PHP - ничего нет. Расскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм действий, кто уже реализовал выбор валюты у себя на сайте...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно должна быть отдельная талбица для валют например  currency:

```
|id_currency|title |value|status |
|1          | рубль|1    |DEFAULT|
|2          | us   |30.25|1      |
```

Цены задаются по умолчанию рублями
при отображения цен можно сделать так например:

```
цена = цена продукта * $_SESSION['currency']
и echo цена;
```

А выбор валют просто вытащите из БД всех валют и по умолчанию в $_SESSION['currency'] засунут рубль, а если пользовател выбрал другую валюту то например $_SESSION['currency']= выбранная валюта($currency->value).

Сильно не судите, это чиста мое мнение.

Comment: Можете объяснить, пожалуйста, зачем Вы используете колонку status?

Comment: Добавлю, что иногда удобно делать ручной ввод цены для товара для каждой валюты (если их немного). Это позволит владельцу выставлять цену, например, для региона вне зависимости от курса. А хранить информацию о том, какую валюту выбрал пользователь можно в его личных настройках, если на сайте есть регистрация, иначе - сессия или куки.

Comment: Это для того чтоб узнать валюту по умолчанию:)